Why are my LED bulbs flickering?
We’re experiencing random flickering of the lights in our household. All the fixtures contain the same LED bulbs. Is it possible that as these wear out and start to flicker that this could feed back into the house wiring in some way causing flicker elsewhere, for instance causing appliances to shut off?

LEDs should not cause stuff to turn off.  LEDs do seem to notice wiring/electrical problems much sooner than other devices.  Flickering and/or turning off of other devices is a sign of a loose wire.  Possible the main wires coming to the house from the pole/transformer.  Your power company will check these wires for free.

And LED bulbs flickering, and What can cause all LED bulbs / fixtures to rapidly flicker at the same rate? and Why are my some of my LED lights flickering? and a bazillion more

If you actually have appliances shutting off in conjunction with the LED flicker you need to revise your post to provide more information about that.
